# How to get rid of edubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, uninstall, edubuntu

Recently I updated my linux to version 16.04. I had also installed edubuntu 14.04 LTS before and on the logging screen I can see that I am running Edubuntu 14.04 LTS. Also when I shut down my computer the last thing I can see is a banner on the top of the screen that says edubuntu.

Sometimes (about 1 of 10 times) my computer freezes on that splash screen and I have to force shutdown. I have already uninstalled all edubuntu packages from my system, but still I am always getting these screen on the startup and shutdown.

Is there some way that I can get rid of Edubuntu completely with out having to install Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 1):

I somehow managed to remove the edubuntu(oldskool way)

Initially it showed the following error

```
dpkg: error processing package edubuntu-artwork (--configure):
 installed edubuntu-artwork package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
```

What i did!

```
sudo find / -maxdepth 5 -name "*edubuntu*" -exec rm -rf {}

sudo apt remove *edubuntu*
```

It showed warning(same for most of the packages)

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'plymouth-theme-edubuntu' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

But it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Edubuntu isn't a completely different operating system from Ubuntu, but a variation. As you might know, Ubuntu (and Linux distributions in general) is organized in packages. Ubuntu offers a large pool of packages. In a default installation of the "standard" Ubuntu distribution, a chosen subset of those packages is installed. In a default installation of Edubuntu, a different subset of those packages is installed.

Later, you can basically "pick and match" as you need, for example, install a package that comes with Edubuntu by default on an Ubuntu system or vice versa. You may run into dependency problems, but "within reason" you can use any software from the large pool on any Ubuntu variant.

By "switching" from Edubuntu to Ubuntu, you probably switched the desktop (not the whole operating system). Other packages, for example the splash screen, are still from the Edubuntu portion of the package pool. That's mostly a cosmetic error.

If you want to change it, make sure you have the Ubuntu desktop installed and uninstall the Edubuntu desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop   # install Ubuntu desktop
sudo apt-get remove edubuntu-desktop  # uninstall Edubuntu desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove # remove dependencies that are no longer needed
```

To change the splash screen to the Ubuntu version, you can do:

```
sudo update-usplash-theme usplash-theme-ubuntu
```

Comment: That last one did not work ( sudo update-usplash-theme usplash-theme-ubuntu ) and I still have the same problem.